How can I have two Haskell programs talk to each other through the internet?
The question in the title is relatively simple, but I don't know how complex the answer can be, nor if the question itself is ill-posed for some reason, so below are more details about the usecase that leads me to think I need what I ask in the title.

(The following information is only informative of my usecase, and any questions in it do not require an answer.)
I wrote a simple terminal-based Snake game, and my intention is to make it a multiplayer online, as an excuse to learn something new I know nothing about yet.
The idea is that the executable, let's call it snake,

without further arguments, would start a single player game, and also print an URL to be shared,
whereas, with an URL as argument, would try to join an existing game in a shared session.

A shared session could mean different things, and I haven't thought about a full plan yet; for instance:

Would the game just happen on one player's process, which would receive keypresses from the other players, update the screen, and send to the other processes only the delta of the screen?
Or would the players send each other's keypresses and each would play the game independently? (This would require that the game is written in such a way that the two or more games can't go out of sync, so it sounds a bit more difficult.)
Regardless, there should be no primary/secondary player, in the sense that if the player that started the game and shared the URL disconnects, the other players should continue the game (in single player, if only one player is left) and the URL should be kept alive so that other players can join.

I see that tty-share¹ must be doing something similar for the purpose of sharing the terminal, but I see in the GitHub page that

When sharing it over the Internet (outside your NAT), tty-share will connect to proxy server that will mediate the communication between the participants.

which seems to be not what I want, specifically for being in contrast with the last bullet above.

(¹) No, it's not Haskell, but given my knowledge of the topic of network programming, that's probably irrelevant.

Where is this URL coming from?  If it doesn't refer to the machine of the starting player, what machine does it refer to?

Do you plan to have a central server that all players will connect to, or do you want the players' computers to directly connect to each other? Note that if you choose the latter, it will be difficult for people not on the same LAN to play against each other, and your requirement that "if the player that started the game and shared the URL disconnects, [...] the URL should be kept alive so that other players can join" would be impossible.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, why impossible? I was imagining that the first player plays the role of the server, but shares enough data that any other player can pick that role up as soon as the server dies. What is unique to the server that makes it impossible to move it to other machines?

@Enlico The server can be moved to other machines, but doing so would invalidate the original URL.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, I guess I'll need to ask some subquestions separately. For instance I don't know what entity generates the URL. I wonder if it's possible for all players to share the same URL generating function, or something like that...

@Enlico No matter how you generate the URL, it will need to uniquely point to the first player's computer, so once the first player quits, a new one would be needed. The only way to avoid that is some kind of central server.

Beware that you are stepping into the very deep and complicated world of distributed systems. It is generally not possible to have a distributed system with all the good properties, so prioritize your requirements and mentally prepare for dropping the low-priority ones. (Examples of impossibility theorems: it is in general not possible for everyone to reliably agree even on a single bit, you may have at most two of consistency, availability, and partition tolerance.)

You may be interested in distributed-process, the implementation of Cloud Haskell. It almost certainly will not meet all your requirements, but it does handle a lot of low-level details that you probably don't want to reinvent. It is described in detail in Jeffrey Epstein's MPhil thesis, Functional programming for the data centre. (Not that Jeffrey Epstein, obviously.)
